# Fetching data with mobx goes into infinity loop

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to fetch a data from server, save it in obserable property and rendering this property whenever request is completed, but I'm in some trouble because my code cause infinity loop of fetching data and re-rendering.
The only difference if I remove useEffect is that *Rendering...* isn't printed 2 times in a row...

React component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react'

const Home = (props) => {
    const { restaurantStore } = props.rootStore;

    console.log('Rendering...');
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Fetching resturant data..');
        restaurantStore.fetchRestaurantInfo();
    }, [])

    return (
        <section className="section-welcome">
            <div className="shell">
                <h1 className="section-title">
                    Welcome to <span>{restaurantStore.name}</span>
                </h1>

               // more not relevant html code
    )
}

export default inject("rootStore")(observer(Home));
```

Store:

```
import { decorate, action, observable } from 'mobx'
import http from '../utils/http-client'

class RestaurantStore {
    rootStore;
    name = 'test';

    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore;
    }

    async fetchRestaurantInfo() {
        this.rootStore.startLoading();
        const restaurant = await http.get('/restaurant/location');
        this.name = restaurant.name;
        this.rootStore.stopLoading();
    }
}

decorate(RestaurantStore, {
    name: observable,
    fetchRestaurantInfo: action
})

export default RestaurantStore
```

Console output:

```
Home.js:7 Rendering...
Home.js:7 Rendering...
Home.js:9 Fetching resturant data..
Home.js:7 Rendering...
Home.js:7 Rendering...
Home.js:9 Fetching resturant data..
```

Comment: My guess is that this is because your `startLoading` and `stopLoading` functions cause the `Home` component to no longer be rendered, and then rendered again, which in turn causes the affect to be called a second time... However, that isn't shown in your code directly. Can you show the relevant code to `startLoading` and `stopLoading`?

Comment: You need to check the parent of the Home component. Most of all it  unmount/mount Home one.

Comment: Yeah the problem was right because of startLoading and stopLoading. In home parent i had loader componenet rendered if loader observable is true, either render the application which is switch with routes and it was caused becase startLoading cause side effect which re-render App.js which re-render Home.js which trigger fetching data again.